# Need help to check array and remove items that are not in sequence

Tags: php, arrays, sequence

I have an array of items:

```
    [3] => Array
    (
        [4] => 05
        [11] => 14
        [12] => 15
    )
```

I want to remove the items that are not in sequence, in this case it is index 4, which contain `05`. The data would look like this:

```
    [3] => Array
    (
        [11] => 14
        [12] => 15
    )
```

Any suggestions on a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: Better than what? Please show what you've tried.

Comment: If you have `4, 5, 13, 14` which would you remove? It has two sequences, but they're separated from each other.

Comment: @Barmar He hasn't tried anything because he doesn't know where to start.

Comment: I would: (a) take a copy of the array, (b) reindex it with `array_values` since keys aren't important, (c) `sort` it, (d) loop through all elements and for each one see if the one before it is one less or the one after it is one more. If neither is true, (e) remove that element.

Comment: Hmm, actually you probably want to preserve keys - don't bother with `array_values` in (b) and use `asort` in step (c).

Comment: @Barmar : i'm not compared yet. i'm confused by the algorithm to check those sequence LOL if i've `4,5,13,14` then there's no need to remove, it based to num of data. my data is not less than 2.

@djay thanks, yeah i didn't tried it yet. i'm just newbie here LOL

Comment: The way to learn to program is to try to do it. You don't learn anything by getting other people to write it for you, it's like painting by numbers or cookie with a prepared mix.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to accomplish this is by learning algorithms, programming in general, and taking practical tests.

Happy decrypting. :)

```
function answer_rahendzs_problem($array){

    $k=$v=NULL;
    $r = array();
    $fc = 0;
    $lp = NULL;

    foreach($array as $key=>$value){ 

        if($k+1!=$key || $v+1!=$value ) {
            if(!isset($k) || !$fc) {
                $k = $key;
                $v = $value;
                $lp = array($key,$value);
            }

            continue;
        }

        if(!$fc){
            $fc = 1;
            if((array)$lp===$lp){
                $r[$lp[0]] = $lp[1];
            }
        }

        $r[$key] = $value;
        $k++; $v++;
    }

    return $r;
}

die("<pre>".print_r(answer_rahendzs_problem(array( 4=>5,11=>14,12=>15 )),true));
```

Comment: thanks bro, i'll try it soon and give here a feedback